# Rails: How to load associations in a single query while customizing association columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

If I use `eager_load` to fetch the association I want in a single query, I get way too many columns:

```
scope = Product.eager_load(:account).to_a
scope.last.account.name
```

Then I get a query that looks like:

```
 SQL (3.3ms)  SELECT "products"."id" AS t0_r0, "products"."account_id" AS t0_r1, "products"."notes" AS t0_r2, "products"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "products"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "products"."rep_id" AS t0_r5, "products"."senior_rep_id" AS t0_r6, "products"."name_id" AS t0_r7...
```

My goal is to just get the columns I want, such as I might expect by calling `.select("intakes.id, intakes.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name")`. However if I add that to my query, it simply prepends that line to the front and basically ignores it:

```
 SQL (3.3ms)  SELECT products.id, products.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name, "products"."id" AS t0_r0, "products"."account_id" AS t0_r1, "products"."notes" AS t0_r2, "products"."created_at" AS t0_r3, "products"."updated_at" AS t0_r4, "products"."rep_id" AS t0_r5, "products"."senior_rep_id" AS t0_r6, "products"."name_id" AS t0_r7...
```

So now my query is even longer, but I didn't get any benefit. I can also try with `left_joins`:

```
scope = Product.left_joins(:account).select("products.id, products.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name").to_a
```

This will yield me N+1 queries, where the select is ignored for associations:

```
Products Load (0.9ms)  SELECT products.id, products.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "products"."account_id"
Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

However I can avoid the N+1 if I recognize the selected columns DID go somewhere, in that `accounts.name` mapped to `name` on the Product:

```
scope.last.attributes["name"]
```

This technically gets me the information I want in a single query, but when building a real query with many associations, trying to rename and remap this data to lots of custom names suddenly makes me wonder why I'm using ActiveModel in the first place. Is there more of a "Rails Way" to do this where `scope.last.account.name` will still have its value set in the way it would had I used `eager_load`?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave query `scope = Product.left_joins(:account).select("products.id, products.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name").to_a` than your second line should be like `scope.last.name` to prevent second db request. If you have same columns in account and product tables set different names for them in select method (i.e. `scope = Product.left_joins(:account).select("products.id, products.account_id, accounts.id, accounts.name as account_name").to_a` than extract it like `scope.last.account_name`.

Comment: That's exactly what I mention doing in the last paragraph, but then I talk about why that's not a good enough solution in my case.